# Get separate explicit render passes without rendering the entire image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-passes

Today I noticed that I need to render some paths separate from the combined path. (Z and AO). I checked the marks, put combined to off and also made the locations clear in the node editor for blender where to save the 2 files. 
However when I start rendering blender still starts to render the whole image. 
I had hoped it wouldn't so that it won't take that much time to just render the AO and Z depth.

What do I have to do in addition to get the combined render off.